# Fixate "Level" colors in Kibana histogram (vertical stacked bar chart) across searches

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, histogram, kibana, serilog

I use Serilog in my ASP.NET Core application to send logs to Elastic. The `Level` field in my `logstash-` indexes will contain values on the typical scale (Verbose, Information, Warning, Error, Fatal). I have a Vertical Stacked Bar Chart / histogram on my dashboard for this field bucketed by the `@timestamp` field.

I'm trying (but failing) to keep the colors associated with the various `Level` values stable. Depending on my filters or selected time period the listed options might differ, and the color palette just shifts colors assigned to values. This can be very confusing.

For example, here's the lens for "Last 7 days" filter:

[image: histogram with 6 different levels and auto-assigned colors]

And here is the same lens for the "Last 15 minutes" filter just now:

[image: histogram with 4 different levels and different auto-assigned colors]

For example the `Error` level gets assigned a different color in the second rendering. Things can become even more extreme if the filters get narrowed down.

[image: histogram with 3 different levels and even different auto-assigned colors]

I tried a few things to fix this (Google searches, and go through the "Break down by" and "Color palette" settings) but found no suitable way to change this. Most notably the "Visual Options" button is disabled for "Bar vertical stacked" visualizations, saying:

> This setting cannot be changed on histograms.

I will mention I'm on a cluster version 7.x of Elastic Cloud, if an upgrade to 8.x promises to fix this it's an option to expedite our upgrade.

What I would prefer to be able to do: explicitly "reserve" a color for each explicit value in this `Level` field, though I'd also be content with any "stable" auto-assigned set of colors.